# Rock Paper Scissors JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple rock paper scissors script for code academy as part of the course; every answer I get is towards the end is the alert("rock wins!") no matter what I put in; what am I doing wrong?

```
var choice1 = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
//-------------------------------------//
var choice2 = Math.random();

if (choice2 < 0.34) {
    choice2 = "rock"
    } 

else if(choice2 <= 0.67) {
    choice2 = "paper";
    } 

else {
    choice2 = "scissors";
    } 

    console.log(choice2)
//------ possible outcomes for the computer are above this comment----------- 


compare = function(choice1,choice2){

//----------------------------------------
if(choice1 === "paper" & choice2 ==="paper"){
    alert("The result is a tie!");}

if(choice1 === "rock" & choice2 ==="rock"){
    alert("The result is a tie!");}

if(choice1 === "scissors" & choice2 ==="scissors"){
    alert("The result is a tie!");}

//-possible outcomes for a tie are above this comment------------------------------


if(choice1 === "paper" & choice2 === "rock"){
    alert("paper wins!");} 


if(choice1 === "rock" & choice2 === "paper"){
    alert("paper wins!");}

 //-possible outcomes for paper & rock are above this comment------------------------


 if(choice1 === "scissors" & choice2 === "rock"){
    alert("rock wins!");} 

if(choice1 === "rock" & choice2 === "scissors"){
    alert("rock wins!");}

//-possible outcomes for a scissors & rock are above this comment--------------------


 if(choice1 === "scissors" & choice2 === "paper"){
    alert("scissors wins!");} 

if(choice1 === "paper" & choice2 === "scissors"){
    alert("scissors wins!");}

//-possible outcomes for a scissors & paper are above this comment--------------

}//<---End of compare function--//
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `&&` for "and", not `&`.

```
if (choice1 === "paper" && choice2 === "rock") {
  ...
```